# PHP ODBC can't connect to SQL Server 2012 with Openssl 1.1.1

Tags: php, sql-server, openssl, odbc, sqlsrv

I've seen parts of this question asked around a few times, but nothing has worked for me yet.

I have an SQL Server 2012 instance running on a Windows server. On my Ubuntu 20.10 server, I am running PHP 7.4.12 on an apache server. I have openssl version 1.1.1 installed.

I followed most of the instructions found in the microsoft docs:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-the-drivers-on-ubuntu-1604-1804-and-2004

but ran into some issues when downloading the msodbcsql17 driver. I had to download it from here instead:

> https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql17/

My PHP script:

```php
<?php

try {
    // Sensitive info is replaced by temporary strings.
    $serverName = "<ip_addr>,<port>";

    $options = array("Database" => "<db_name>", "UID" => "<user_name>", "PWD" => "<password>");

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $options);

    if ($conn == false) {
        var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());
        die();
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo("Error!");
}
```

Here is the error printed out from the `var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());` in the code above:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "08001"
    ["SQLSTATE"]=>
    string(5) "08001"
    [1]=>
    int(10054)
    ["code"]=>
    int(10054)
    [2]=>
    string(73) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746"
    ["message"]=>
    string(73) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "08001"
    ["SQLSTATE"]=>
    string(5) "08001"
    [1]=>
    int(10054)
    ["code"]=>
    int(10054)
    [2]=>
    string(79) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection"
    ["message"]=>
    string(79) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection"
  }
}
```

I saw this potential solution here: https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1021#issuecomment-520943561 but there is no line `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL-2` in the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` file as the answer states. I tried adding `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1` to the end of the file anyway, but nothing changed.

What can I do to fix this error in the connection? Is the only other option to downgrade openssl versions? I've read that it can break many packages and cause issues down the line. I can't take the SQL Server offline to upgrade to a newer SQL version either.

I have made sure that the SQL Server is accepting remote connections as I can make an ODBC connection to the SQL Server from another machine using Crystal Reports.

**EDIT: openssl command results**

Here are the results which printed immediately after running:

```
openssl s_client -host <ip_addr> -port <port> -tls1
```

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
139710250579264:error:141E70BF:SSL routines:tls_construct_client_hello:no protoc                                           ols available:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1112:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 7 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Here are the results after running:

```
openssl s_client -host <ip_addr> -port <port> -tls1_2
```

and it stayed open for a while and then finally after not entering anything it printed this:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 188 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1605916005
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

Comment: Please tell us what windows server are you using ?　(.e.g. SQL server 2012 on win server 2008 ??)

Comment: As a starting point you can determine which TLS versions your server supports using `openssl s_client -host ipaddr -port port -tls1` for TLS 1.0, `-tls1_1` for TLS 1.1 and `-tls1_2` for TLS 1.2. If none of them connect successfully then it's probably a firewall issue.

Comment: @KenLee I am using windows server 2012 R2

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I added the results of both of the openssl commands

Comment: @AlwaysLearning any ideas on this?

Comment: Well you've established that you can get connections with TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2, so possibly you have configuration issues in your /etc/odbc.ini or ~/.odbc.ini files. Have a read through [Connecting to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connection-string-keywords-and-data-source-names-dsns), and maybe try setting up a DSN there, maybe even with `Encrypt=no` so see if the issue is even TLS-related at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late now. Try `MinProtocol = TLSv1.0` in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`. This works fine for me (https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1023#issuecomment-523214695)